# Swift string does not escape double quotes

Tags: string, swift

Very strange issue, I feel like I'm missing something very simple but cannot figure it out. I'm trying to build an XML body like so:

```
let bodyString = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><UserNameLoginRequest xmlns=\"\(PSS_XML_DEFAULT_NAMESPACE)\" from=\"\(LoginManager.clientID)\"><UserName>\(username)</UserName><UserPassword>\(password)</UserPassword><ClientType>\(clientType)</ClientType></UserNameLoginRequest>"
```

But what comes out is this (URL and credentials redacted):

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding= \"UTF-8\"?><UserNameLoginRequest xmlns=\"http://example.com/\" from=\"myDeviceID\"><UserName>000</UserName><UserPassword>1234</UserPassword><ClientType>myClientType</ClientType></UserNameLoginRequest>
```

Note the backslashes. Obviously this isn't valid XML and doesn't work. So...what am I missing?

Comment: This works fine for me, are you using `print` to see the output?

Answer (score 1):

```
let username = "user"
let password = "pswd"
let clientType = 0
struct LoginManager {
    static let clientID = 100
}

let bodyString = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><UserNameLoginRequest xmlns=\"\\(PSS_XML_DEFAULT_NAMESPACE)\" from=\"\(LoginManager.clientID)\"><UserName>\(username)</UserName><UserPassword>\(password)</UserPassword><ClientType>\(clientType)</ClientType></UserNameLoginRequest>"
print(bodyString)
```

backslash MUST be escaped too!!!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><UserNameLoginRequest xmlns="\(PSS_XML_DEFAULT_NAMESPACE)" from="100"><UserName>user</UserName><UserPassword>pswd</UserPassword><ClientType>0</ClientType></UserNameLoginRequest>
```

example

```
print("a\"\\b") //prints      a"\b
```

Comment: I don't understand...I'm not trying to escape any backslashes, I'm trying to escape the double quotes.

Comment: print("a\"\\b") //prints      a"\b

Comment: if " should be part of string it must be 'escaped' with \. if \ should be part of string, it must be escaped too ...